# PostgreSQL Performance Worsening

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm running a PostgreSQL DB on a windows VM. Every morning I run some large customer matching algorithms which run in 10-15 minutes. However, recently, the machine has begun to take longer and longer to run the job.. and creeps all the way up to 6 hours in some cases. When we restart the VM it reduces back down to about 10-15 minutes... but again the creeping begins over the course of the next two weeks until we are forced to restart again.

The machine comfortably operates within the allowed RAM in the first few days after restart but appears to eat up more and more RAM in line with processing time increasing.

My question is, what are the most likely causes of this? We are confident that the code is not doing anything silly but possibly there is a cache somewhere which grows over time..? any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!!

Comment: Are you running VACUUM every once in a while (daily at night) ? See [this article about vacuum.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT)

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

Comment: Are you properly releasing all resources? e.g. properly ending transactions, closing un-used connections? Do you have connections in the state `idle in transaction`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but there are no connections in idle state... I have noticed that even when the machine is doing nothing the RAM is still at about 33% i.e. 10GB. When I look at the Resource monitor there are a number of javaw.exe imagines which are at the root of the 30%. Are they lingering imagines from Talend?

Comment: Finally got to the bottom of it! We were using an ETL tool on top of PostgreSQL. One developer was leaving his ETL session open continuously which after about two weeks had swallowed up most of the RAM! Thanks for all your help!